# How to proceed on package.el signature check failure

Tags: package, package-repositories

I just tried to install `ascii-art-to-unicode` from the gnu repository (http://elpa.gnu.org/) via `list-packages`. I get the following error:

```
package--check-signature: Failed to verify signature 
   ascii-art-to-unicode-1.9.el.sig: ("No public key 
   for 474F05837FBDEF9B created at 2014-09-24T16:20:01+0200 
   using DSA")
```

I'm using cask/pallet to manage my packages; is there some setup I missed? Some recent changes to elpa?

I'm using an emacs 24.4 pre-release.

Comment: I had a similar problem today updating org-mode from elpa (though I used package.el). Might be a temporary problem with their servers.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

1. set `package-check-signature` to `nil`, e.g. `M-: (setq package-check-signature nil) RET`
2. download the package `gnu-elpa-keyring-update` and run the function with the same name, e.g. `M-x package-install RET gnu-elpa-keyring-update RET`.
3. reset `package-check-signature` to the default value `allow-unsigned`, e.g. `M-: (setq package-check-signature "allow-unsigned") RET`

This worked for me.

As stated in the package the following holds:

If your keys are already too old, causing signature verification errors when
installing packages, then in order to install this package you can do the
following:

- Fetch the new key manually, e.g. with something like:

  ```
  gpg --homedir ~/.emacs.d/elpa/gnupg --receive-keys 066DAFCB81E42C40
  ```
- Modify the expiration date of the old key, e.g. with something like:

  ```
  gpg --homedir ~/.emacs.d/elpa/gnupg \
      --quick-set-expire 474F05837FBDEF9B 1y
  ```
- temporarily disable signature verification (see variable
  `package-check-signature').

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary to explicitly run the function: installing the package should be sufficient because it should run the function for you automatically.

Comment: Ahh ok. Hard to test it now that it works, but I think you're right.

Comment: In case someone else is as confused as me: the command for step 3 is `M-: (setq package-check-signature "allow-unsigned") RET` with quotations

Comment: When trying to install gnu-elpa-keyring-update, I only get a [no match] message. Could you please help @joe_maya

Comment: @Leo try `M-x package-refresh-contents` before installing `gnu-elpa-keyring-update`, it should solve the [no match] issue

Answer (score 17):

FWIW - I had this issue with the signature org-20140407.tar.sig.  Like Sigma's **package-check-signature** is/was **allow-unsigned**.

I changed the **package-check-signature** value to **nil** and the problem was resolved.

Comment: Thanks! I would never guess that "allow-unsigned" doesn't mean what it supposed to mean...

Comment: If you set it to nil, make sure you access the `elpa.gnu.org` repository via HTTPS, otherwise you're opening yourself to easy security attacks.

Comment: @avp: `allow-unsigned` means that you allow installing packages which don't have signatures.  But this package *does* have a signature (one you can't check because you don't have the needed key in your keyring)!

Answer (score 15):

If you try to install the package `gnu-elpa-keyring-update` (which seems to have the purpose of updating the keys used by the package manager), you  will see in its description that you can do:

`gpg --homedir ~/.emacs.d/elpa/gnupg --receive-keys 066DAFCB81E42C40`

on the commandline to get new keys manually.  To make sure you are asking for the correct key (`066DAFCB81E42C40` in the example above), check the error message that emacs gives you when you try to install any package.

Comment: this command gives me an error: "gpg: keyserver receive failed: Server indicated a failure" (Windows 10 Pro + WSL 2  +Ubuntu 18.04)

Comment: same on Ubuntu 18.04 (native)

Answer (score 5):

It appears that the key used to sign this package (474F05837FBDEF9B) is indeed not published (therefore cannot be signed, therefore cannot be trusted).
But it would seem that package.el is supposed to fail gracefully (for now) in such cases:

```
;; If package-check-signature is allow-unsigned, don't
;; signal error when we can't verify signature because of
;; missing public key.  Other errors are still treated as
;; fatal (bug#17625).
(unless (and (eq package-check-signature 'allow-unsigned)
             (eq (epg-signature-status sig) 'no-pubkey))
  (setq had-fatal-error t))
```

So I'm wondering if for some reason your value of `package-check-signature` is different than its default value of `allow-unsigned` ?

Comment: `package-check-signature` is `allow-unsigned`; that leaves the `epg-signature-status` -- hmm.

Comment: `sig=[cl-struct-epg-signature bad 474F05837FBDEF9B nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil] status=bad` - note that the problem is still present.

Comment: `allow-unsigned` means to allow installation of packages that are not signed, as opposed to packages which are signed but whose signature you're not able to verify.  This is used so you can install from ELPA archives which don't sign their packages (MELPA was like that last time I checked).

Answer (score 5):

The answers here are a bit dated. This issue seems to have been fixed as of emacs 26.3.

Comment: Emacs 27.2 on Windows has the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you could upgrade to a newer emacs, e.g. on Ubuntu:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-elisp/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install emacs-snapshot
```

This way you avoid doing all this: https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/gnu-elpa-keyring-update.html

Answer (score 2):

get the puglic key with:

```
gpg2 --homedir ~/.emacs.d/elpa/gnupg --receive-keys 066DAFCB81E42C40
```

**Attention:**
your version could be a different key !

Answer (score 1):

Setting `package-check-signature` to `nil` instead of the default `allow-unsigned` fixed this for me.

Fedora 29, GNU Emacs 26.2 (build 1, x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.8)
 of 2019-04-30

Comment: how do I set "package-check-signature to nil" ? which file do I need to edit? init.el?

Answer (score 0):

I get:

```
 % gpg --homedir ~/.emacs.d/elpa/gnupg --receive-keys 066DAFCB81E42C40
gpg: key 066DAFCB81E42C40: new key but contains no user ID - skipped
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:           w/o user IDs: 1
```