# Can not connect to a package archive?

Tags: package-repositories

I was trying to install [beacon](https://melpa.org/#/beacon) and got this error,

```
package--check-signature-content: Failed to verify signature: "seq-2.20.tar.sig"
```

Before installing, I ran `package-refresh-content` which gave an error about the verification of a public key in `*Error*`:

```
Failed to verify signature seq-2.20.tar.sig:
No public key for <some id> created at 2019-09-21T12:54:43-0500 using RSA
Command output:
gpg: Signature made Sat 21 Sep 2019 12:54:43 PM CDT
gpg:                using RSA key <some key>
gpg: Can't check signature: No public key
```

There was also this error in the `*Messages*` buffer,

```
Contacting host: elpa.gnu.org:80 [2 times]
Failed to download ‘gnu’ archive.
```

Here is how my `.emacs` file's package archives variable looks like,

```lisp
(setq package-archives '(("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
             ;; ("marmalade" . "https://marmalade-repo.org/packages/")
             ("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/")))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to proceed on package.el signature check failure](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/233/how-to-proceed-on-package-el-signature-check-failure)