# Cannot run melpa package refresh due to gpg errors

Tags: package-repositories, gpg

Root task: trying to install R mode for emacs (ESS following - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422987/emacs-mode-for-r)

OS: Ubuntu 18.04

Problem: When I run `M-x package-refresh-contents RET`

I get the following error:

```
Failed to verify signature archive-contents.sig:
No public key for 066DAFCB81E42C40 created at 2020-09-08T10:05:02+0100 using RSA
Command output:
gpg: WARNING: unsafe permissions on homedir '/home/xxx/.emacs.d/elpa/gnupg'
gpg: Signature made Tue 08 Sep 2020 10:05:02 BST
gpg:                using RSA key C433554766D3DDC64221BFAA066DAFCB81E42C40
gpg: Can't check signature: No public key
```

I tried following the accepted answer at: [How to proceed on package.el signature check failure](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/233/how-to-proceed-on-package-el-signature-check-failure)

Updating the public keys using `M-x package-install RET gnu-elpa-keyring-update RET` gives `[No match]`.

If I try to update the keys manually using gpg:

```
gpg --homedir ~/.emacs.d/elpa/gnupg --receive-keys 066DAFCB81E42C40
```

gives

```
gpg: WARNING: unsafe permissions on homedir '/home/xxx/.emacs.d/elpa/gnupg'
gpg: keyserver receive failed: General error
```

Sure enough if I go to keyserver.ubuntu.com and search for the fingerprint I find nothing. Furthermore, if I try to extend the expiration date of the old key (another workaround suggested):

```
gpg  --quick-set-expire 474F05837FBDEF9B 1y
```

gives

```
gpg: "474F05837FBDEF9B" is not a fingerprint
```

Can anyone explain why this is failing? I'm not massively familiar with gpg.

**Update**

Following advice in the comments I managed to fix the permissions on `~/.emacs.d/elpa/gnupg` so the warning is gone, however the error persists. Running `M-x package-refresh-contents RET` now results in:

```
Failed to verify signature archive-contents.sig:
No public key for 066DAFCB81E42C40 created at 2020-09-09T10:05:02+0100 using RSA
Command output:
gpg: Signature made Wed 09 Sep 2020 10:05:02 BST
gpg:                using RSA key C433554766D3DDC64221BFAA066DAFCB81E42C40
gpg: Can't check signature: No public key
```

Similarly, running:
`gpg --homedir ~/.emacs.d/elpa/gnupg --receive-keys 066DAFCB81E42C40`

just gives:

`gpg: keyserver receive failed: General error`

Comment: What are the permissions of `~/.emacs.d/elpa/gnupg`?  They probably need to be `drwx------`.

Comment: ```drwxr-xr-x  8 xxx xxx      4096 Sep  8 11:15  .emacs.d``` I couldn't figure out why this warning appeared either, I don't think I've ever touched the permissions.

Comment: They are  700 for me: change the permissions and try again. It might eliminate the problem or at least eliminate the permissions as the source of the problem

Comment: Just realised how stupid my last comment was. The permissions on ```~/.emacs.d/elpa/gnupg``` were wrong. I've fixed them and the issue persists. Update above.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. It seems like gpg is not able to locate a key server.

To fix it, in the `~/.emacs.d/elpa/gnupg` directory, create a file named `gpg.conf` with the following line:

```
keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com
```

Then run this on the command line:

```
gpg --homedir ~/.emacs.d/elpa/gnupg --receive-keys 066DAFCB81E42C40
```

And then in emacs:

```
M-x package-refresh-contents RET
```

Comment: `gpg: keyserver receive failed: No name`

Comment: Updated to new key server. keys.gnupg.net is gone now.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
gpg --homedir ~/.emacs.d/elpa/gnupg --keyserver hkps://keys.openpgp.org --recv-keys 066DAFCB81E42C40
```

You might also like to add `keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net` to your `~/.emacs.d/elpa/gnupg/gpg.conf` file

And finally don't forget to run `M-x package-refresh-contents RET`

Answer (score 0):

Run this on the command line:

```
gpg --homedir ~/.emacs.d/elpa/gnupg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com --receive-keys 066DAFCB81E42C40
```

Then, inside Emacs, download descriptions of all configured ELPA packages:

```
M-x package-refresh-contents RET
```