# when ı install jedi and melpa package emacs give error about initialization file

Tags: init-file, package, install

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/") t)
;; Comment/uncomment this line to enable MELPA Stable if desired.  See `package-archive-priorities`                                                                     
;; and `package-pinned-packages`. Most users will not need or want to do this.                                                                                          
;;(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa-stable" . "https://stable.melpa.org/packages/") t)                                                                            
(package-initialize)

;;; jedi completion                                                                                                                                                     
;;; see https://github.com/tkf/emacs-jedi                                                                                                                               

;; jedi dependency: deferred                                                                                                                                            
(add-to-list 'load-path (expand-file-name
                         "~/.emacs.d/el-get/deferred"))
;; jedi dependency: deferred                                                                                                                                            
(add-to-list 'load-path (expand-file-name
                         "~/.emacs.d/el-get/ctable"))
;; jedi dependency: epc                                                                                                                                                 
(add-to-list 'load-path (expand-file-name
                         "~/.emacs.d/el-get/epc"))
(add-to-list 'load-path (expand-file-name
                         "~/.emacs.d/el-get/jedi"))
(require 'jedi)
(setq jedi:server-args
      '("--sys-path" "/usr/lib/python2.7/"
        "--sys-path" "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages"))

(setq jedi:setup-keys t)
```

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading ‘/home/tuna/.emacs’:

File is missing: Cannot open load file, There is no such file or directory, jedi

To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with
the ‘--debug-init’ option to view a complete error backtrace. Disable showing Disable logging
```

ı am new in using emacs and ı dont know how can ı install and use packages so what is basic alghoritm of install packages to emacs? when do ı use M-x shortcut when do ı add codes to initialization file? (ı mean .emacs file)

Comment: What error does it give? I put the code above in  a file  `stuff.el` and starting emacs with `emacs -Q -l /path/to/file/stuff.el` - I got no error. So when/where did you get the error and what did it say?

Comment: ı got this error: Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading ‘/home/tuna/.emacs’:

File is missing: Cannot open load file, There is no such file or directory, jedi

To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with
the ‘--debug-init’ option to view a complete error backtrace. Disable showing Disable logging

Comment: I got same error when I do same thing you do

Comment: Then I think you must be doing something wrong: I don't think `emacs -Q` worries about the `.emacs` file at all (but I haven't tested, so there is always the possibility that I am mistaken).

Comment: ı delete codes about jedi installation in .emacs file and ı use M-x shortcut and package-install RET jedi so seems like download jedi but ı got new error can ı continue from here or should I open new ask?

Comment: Up to you: in its current form, the question cannot be answered without much additional detail. Personally, I would probably close this question and create a new, better one, with no extra "chaff" to confuse the issue, but including all the details necessary to understand the situation (e.g. describing what you have done in detail, but making sure that your description does not include irrelevant details, so that somebody else can *quickly* reproduce the problem).

Comment: ı just delete jedi installation code in .emacs file so there is just melpa installation codes in my .emacs file ı restart the emacs and ı use M-x shortcut and ı wrote package-install RET jedi so jedi downloaded and there is no error about .emacs file but ı got error like this: Error while verifying signature archive-contents.sig: ı am looking at https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/233/how-to-proceed-on-package-el-signature-check-failure but ı can not install gnu-elpa-keyring-update anyways ı will open new ask about this

Comment: but ı wont close this question because there is no answer about when should ı use write codes to .emacs file for installation and when should ı use M-x shortcut? what is basic alghoritm/logic of installation packages to emacs?

Comment: Then you should edit it down to exactly what you want to ask: there is a lot of irrelevant detail in it, that confuses the issue. However, the questions you mention are not particularly well defined and to some extent are a matter of opinion: people use whatever method helps them accomplish what they need to accomplish. To that extent, a question like that is not appropriate for this site: discussions about what is "best" are appropriate for something like the [Emacs subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/) - here, they will be closed as `Opinion-based`.

Comment: ı create post about my question in emacs subreddit, if there is anybody who wonder he/she should visit this url https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/zpjl05/what_is_basic_alghoritmlogic_of_installation/

Comment: And you've already got some comments! I think there is no reason to keep this question now, so you can close it.