# Error while verifying signature archive-contents.sig: error and ı can not install gnu-elpa-keyring-update

Tags: package, package-repositories, install

ı am using emacs 28.2 in manjaro linux and ı got error like this `Error while verifying signature archive-contents.sig:` when ı install jedi with M-x shortcut
ı am looking at to this url [How to proceed on package.el signature check failure](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/233/how-to-proceed-on-package-el-signature-check-failure) but ı can not install **gnu-elpa-keyring-update** package because when ı write `gnu-elpa-TAB` M-x gives [No match]

package-archives values is:

```
package-archives is a variable defined in ‘package.el’.

Its value is
(("gnu" . "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
 ("nongnu" . "https://elpa.nongnu.org/nongnu/")
 ("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/"))
Original value was 
(("gnu" . "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
 ("nongnu" . "https://elpa.nongnu.org/nongnu/"))

An alist of archives from which to fetch.
The default value points to the GNU Emacs package repository.

Each element has the form (ID . LOCATION).
 ID is an archive name, as a string.
 LOCATION specifies the base location for the archive.
  If it starts with "http(s):", it is treated as an HTTP(S) URL;
  otherwise it should be an absolute directory name.
  (Other types of URL are currently not supported.)

Only add locations that you trust, since fetching and installing
a package can run arbitrary code.

HTTPS URLs should be used where possible, as they offer superior
security.

  This variable may be risky if used as a file-local variable.
  This variable was introduced, or its default value was changed, in
  version 28.1 of Emacs.
  You can customize this variable.
```

init file is:

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/") t)

(package-initialize)
(custom-set-variables
 '(package-selected-packages '(jedi)))
(custom-set-faces
```

there is comment lines but ı dont add them into here

ı have /tmo/foo.el file what contains this codes

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/") t)
```

and ı open emacs with this codes

```
emacs -Q -l /tmp/foo.el
```

and ı write this codes in my terminal

```
curl -X GET https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/ | grep gnu-elpa                             
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:02 --:--:--     0<tr><td><a href="gnu-elpa.html">gnu-elpa</a></td><td>1.1</td><td>Advertize GNU ELPA packages</td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="gnu-elpa-keyring-update.html">gnu-elpa-keyring-update</a></td><td>2019.3</td><td>Update Emacs's GPG keyring for GNU ELPA</td></tr>
100 44535  100 44535    0     0  11322      0  0:00:03  0:00:03 --:--:-- 11323
```

and ı open again my emacs with emacs -Q -l

```
M-x package-install RET gnu-elpa
```

and nothing changed

**this paragraph was answer because of ı installed gnu-elpa-keyring-update but ı have still same problem ı copied my answer to here**

- ı remove emacs and foo.el and .emacs files and reinstall emacs
- ı typed ALT key with SHIFT + : (so ı mean M-: ) and ı write (setq package-check-signature nil)
- ı dont close emacs and ı type M-x package-install RET gnu-elpa-keyring-update

**answer finished**

- ı tried reset package-check-signature to the default value allow-unsigned, e.g. M-: (setq package-check-signature "allow-unsigned") RET

ı follow answer in this question [link](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/233/how-to-proceed-on-package-el-signature-check-failure) and ı wrote codes about gpg to my terminal but nothing changed

```
gpg --homedir ~/.emacs.d/elpa/gnupg --receive-keys 066DAFCB81E42C40             
gpg: key 066DAFCB81E42C40: "GNU ELPA Signing Agent (2019) <elpasign@elpa.gnu.org>" no change
gpg: total amount processed: 1
gpg:                    no change: 1
```

Comment: What `M-x shortcut` is that?

Comment: when we write package install to we should press the ALT + X keys together so this combination is M-x shortcut, maybe not shortcut but definetly understandable ı think?

Comment: What I am asking is what *exactly* you type *after* you type `M-x`.

Comment: firstly ı typed M-: and (setq package-check-signature nil) RET, second ı typed M-x and ı wrote package-install, ı wrote gnu-elpa and typed TAB but ı saw [No match] ?

Comment: What is the value of `package-archives`? Do `C-h v package-archives` to find out and edit your question to add that information. In general, at this point, the more information you provide the better, otherwise we have to extract every bit by asking you. In particular, add the (relevant portion of your) init file to your question.

Comment: ı did what you want, ı typed C-h v package-archives and ı add output into here also ı added init file( .emacs file) so you can see what you needed in my question

Comment: It may be that completion does not work. What happens if you say `M-x package-install gnu-elpa-keyring-update RET` specifying the package completely?

Comment: Note also that what you describe above is not quite what I asked you to do (e.g. when you used `emacs -Q -l /tmp/foo.el` to start emacs, did you do `M-x package-install gnu-elpa-<TAB>` *in that session*? Why is that separate from the `emacs -Q -l` invocation at the end and why is there no file specified there? If you don't follow directions *exactly* then I'm left guessing about what you did exactly: if that continues, I will stop trying to help.

Comment: I wrote all my actions respectively in my question, ı have /tmp/foo.el file and this file contains (require package) codes about melpa but to be honest when ı edited my foo.el file, ı closed my emacs and reopened with emacs -Q -l /tmp/foo.el code and ı tried M-x package install RET gnu-elpa<TAB> but ı get [No match] this is my first try

Comment: today ı try again and this is my second try: ı remove /tmp/foo.el file and create 'emacs -Q -l /tmp/foo.el ' and ı write (require package) codes about melpa so ı save with C-x C-s and ı type M-x package install RET gnu-elpa<TAB> so ı get [No match] (different thing is ı dont close emacs like my first try) ı get second thing: emacs give same error in my question (verifying signature archive-contents.sig error) and ı tried 'curl -X GET https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/ | grep gnu-elpa' code in my all tries

Comment: if you want we can meet in google meet as live and when ı do your says, you can watch me and see my do? to be honest when we meet in google meet ı wont speak(ı dont trust my speak and listening english skills) and ı wont open my camera ı share my all screen and ı will chat with you

Comment: ı tried write gnu-elpa-keyring-update RET but nothings change

Comment: OK - I don't really know what's going on still, but you seem to be doing the things I am asking you to do, correctly: apologies for doubting you. If you start with `emacs -Q -l /tmp/foo.el` and the singe-line `/tmp/foo.el` that just requires `package`, i.e. the file consists of a single line like this: `(require 'package)`, and then you do `M-x package-list-packages`, do you get a buffer listing all the packages available? If you switch to that buffer and you search for `gnu-elpa` (e.g. with `C-s`), do you find anything?

Comment: no, ı can not find anything about gnu-package maybe we should search another package? maybe emacs really dont have gnu-elpa and maybe replace with another thing?

Comment: What version of emacs are you using? `M-x emacs-version` shows you that. Please update the question with the information.