Install magit package failed to verify signature seq-2.24.tar.sig
New emacs user here. Trying to install magit, I ran into signature issues.
I followed the instructions from https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/53142 and successfully installed gnu-elpa-keyring-update in order to update the signatures. I then tried to install magit and got the following:
Failed to verify signature seq-2.24.tar.sig:
Good signature from 645357D2883A0966 GNU ELPA Signing Agent (2023) <elpasign@elpa.gnu.org> (trust undefined) created at 2024-03-31T06:55:14-0300 using (unknown algorithm 22)
Signature made by expired key 066DAFCB81E42C40 GNU ELPA Signing Agent (2019) <elpasign@elpa.gnu.org>
Command output:
gpg: Signature made Sun 31 Mar 2024 06:55:14 AM -03
gpg:                using RSA key C433554766D3DDC64221BFAA066DAFCB81E42C40
gpg: Good signature from "GNU ELPA Signing Agent (2019) <elpasign@elpa.gnu.org>" [expired]
gpg: Note: This key has expired!
Primary key fingerprint: C433 5547 66D3 DDC6 4221  BFAA 066D AFCB 81E4 2C40
gpg: Signature made Sun 31 Mar 2024 06:55:14 AM -03
gpg:                using EDDSA key 0327BE68D64D9A1A66859F15645357D2883A0966
gpg: Good signature from "GNU ELPA Signing Agent (2023) <elpasign@elpa.gnu.org>" [unknown]
gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
Primary key fingerprint: AC49 B8A5 FDED 6931 F40E  E78B F993 C037 86DE 7ECA
     Subkey fingerprint: 0327 BE68 D64D 9A1A 6685  9F15 6453 57D2 883A 0966

I'm running Emacs 26.3 on Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS (focal).
These are the keys that I have inside my .emacs.d/elpa/gnupg
myuser@desk:~/.emacs.d/elpa$ gpg --homedir gnupg/ --list-keys
/home/myuser/.emacs.d/elpa/gnupg/pubring.kbx
---------------------------------------------
pub   dsa2048 2014-09-24 [SC] [expired: 2019-09-23]
      CA442C00F91774F17F59D9B0474F05837FBDEF9B
uid           [ expired] GNU ELPA Signing Agent (2014) <elpasign@elpa.gnu.org>

pub   rsa3072 2019-04-23 [SC] [expired: 2024-04-21]
      C433554766D3DDC64221BFAA066DAFCB81E42C40
uid           [ expired] GNU ELPA Signing Agent (2019) <elpasign@elpa.gnu.org>

pub   ed25519 2022-12-28 [C] [expires: 2032-12-25]
      AC49B8A5FDED6931F40EE78BF993C03786DE7ECA
uid           [ unknown] GNU ELPA Signing Agent (2023) <elpasign@elpa.gnu.org>
sub   ed25519 2022-12-28 [S] [expires: 2027-12-27]


How are you trying to install?

I update the package list (M-x package-refresh-contents) and then I try to install (M-x package-install RET magit)
